Can it be proven that the sum of the mean of n terms raised to the n will always be greater than the product of n terms, for any even integer n?
I've been working on this for a while now.
For a function $f(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=(\frac{(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)}{n})^n-(a_1)(a_2)...(a_n)$, where n is an even integer, can we prove that this function is always $>0$?
So far, I've found that where $a_1+a_2+...+a_n$ is denoted as $b$, and $(a_1)(a_2)...(a_n)$ as $c$ (just for easier notation), we can find $\frac{b^n-n^nc}{n^n}$, and I'm stumped trying to prove this is always positive for an even number n.
Thank you very much, and apologies if the tags aren't quite accurate, I don't know exactly what to tag this with.

Is this not simply the AM-GM inequality?

This is always true if $a_i>0$ otherwise there are counterexamples ( one counterexample is $a_1=1$, $a_2=1$, $a_3=-1$ and $a_4=-1$)
